# How do I make a sequelize query that also returns data from a table linked to from my junction table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite, sequelize.js

These are not my specific tables but what I'm trying to accomplish is the same so don't get caught up too much in the basic library/book example.

Let's say I have some tables/models:

1. `books`

   - book_id (int, pk)
   - name (varchar)
2. `users`

   - user_id (int, pk)
   - name (varchar)
3. `bookusers` (junction table)

   - bookusers_id (int, pk, probably not necessary, but not hurting anything)
   - users_id (fk to users table)
   - books_id (fk to books table)
   - library_id (fk to libraries table)
4. `libraries`

   - library_id (int, pk)
   - name (varchar)

`Books` and `Users` have a m:n relationship. A book could be checked out by many users, and users can check out many books. The `bookusers` table is the junction table between them that stores what's actually checked out and to whom. In addition, I'm storing the ID of the library where it was checked out, which is a foreign key to a `libraries` table.

With that said, here's what I can't figure out. I want to make a query in my node app using Sequelize that returns all of the books checked out by a specific person, including the library information where it was checked out.

Here's what I have so far:

- For example's sake, let's say the user ID whose info I want is `2`
- `User` -> Sequelize model for users table
- `Book` -> Sequelize model for books
- `BookUsers` -> Sequelize model for bookusers
- `Library` -> Sequelize model for libraries

Code:

```
User.findOne({
  where: { id: 2 },
  include: [{ model: Book }],
}).then((user) => {
  console.log(user);
}).catch((err) => {
  // handle error
});
```

This logs something like:

```
{
  "user_id": 2,
  "name": "Jane Doe",
  "Books": [
    {
      "book_id": 1,
      "name": "Moby Dick",
      "BookUser": {
        "bookusers_id": 1,
        "user_id": 2,
        "book_id": 1,
        "library_id": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is working as I'd expect it to. It returns a user with all of the books that she currently has checked out. What I also want and can't figure out, is how I can also get the library information in this query.

Something like this:

```
User.findOne({
  where: { id: 2 },
  through: { include: [{ model: ToolType }]}, // not valid
  include: [{ model: Book }]
}).then((user) => {
  console.log(user);
}).catch((err) => {
  // handle error
});
```

Response:

```
{
  "user_id": 2,
  "name": "Jane Doe",
  "Books": [
    {
      "book_id": 1,
      "name": "Moby Dick",
      "BookUser": {
        "bookusers_id": 1,
        "user_id": 2,
        "book_id": 1,
        "library_id": 1,
        "Library": {
          "library_id": 1,
          "name": "Carnegie Library"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are my current associations between the tables:

```
User.belongsToMany(Book, { through: { model: 'BookUsers' }});
Book.belongsToMany(User, { through: { model: 'User' }});
BookUsers.hasMany(Library, { through: { model: 'Library' }});
```

The first two associations are working fine for including the list of books with the user. The `BookUsers` one, I have no clue if that's correct or what it should be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Or link me to other questions where this has been answered. I couldn't find them!

**Notes:**

- Sequelize version: `4.37.10`
- DB: `sqlite3`
- Nodejs: `8.11.1`
- It's not easy to change the database tables/structure (used by others)

---

**UPDATE**

I did find a solution for now using async/await. It is dirty and doesn't use sequelize, but I'll use it until I figure something out.

```
User.findOne({
  where: { id: 2 },
  include: [{ model: Book }]
}).then((user) => {
  user.Books.map((book) => book.dataValues);
  (async() => {
    for (let i=0;i<user.Books.length;i++) {
      user.Books[i].dataValues.library = await Library.findById(user.Books[i].BookUsers.library_id);
    }
  console.log(user);
  })();
}).catch((err) => {
  // handle error
});
```

Comment: i think it should be `Library.belongsTo(Book, { through: { model: 'BookUsers' }});`

Comment: I can never figure out when to use belongsTo or has Many